# How to strip off formatting in Quill image editor

Tags: html, angularjs, image, upload, quill

Currently quill editor will save the image in base64 image format. That is fine for now.

But how do I make sure quill save the base64 content only and without those formatting?

This is how it would look like after the image has been saved in the db.

```
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></p>
```

Basically I want to strip off "**< p >**" and **< img src=** tags.

I would like to retain **data:image/png;base64,iVBXXXXXXXXXX** only. Is there any setting that I can do on quill modules?

Answer (score 0):

If slicing the string is a doable approach, something like this should work for your current format:

```
var str = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></p>'
var srcPosition = str.indexOf('src');
var pEndPosition = str.indexOf('</p>');
var strippedString = str.slice(srcPosition + 5, pEndPosition - 2);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Not what I'm looking for. But anyway thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about modules but you could use something something like the below to get all the images into an array:

```
function GetImageData(str) {
    var retArray = [];
    var regexPattern = /src="([^"]+)/gi;
    var matches = str.match(regex);
    for (var i = 0;i < matches.length;i++) {
        retArray.push(matches[i].replace('src="',''));
    }
    return retArray;
}

var test = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></p><p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"></p><p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"></p>';

var result = GetImageData(test);
```

This gives you an array with the following:

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
"data:image/png;base64,iVBYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
"data:image/png;base64,iVBZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"
```